# How to set color for negative bar in Kendo bar chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How to change the color of bars in the negative axis? currently the bar has green color. How would i change the color to red? Here is the link for the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPUr4/160/

Html code:

```html
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function createChart() {
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Site Visitors"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "column",

                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    background: "transparent",

                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Total Visits",
                data: series1,
                gap: 1.0,
                spacing: 0,

            } ],
            valueAxis: {
                min: -200000,
                max: 200000,
                axisCrossingValue: 50000, 

                line: {
                    visible: true
                },
                title: {
                    text: "Availability"
                },
               minorGridLines: {
                    visible: false,
                },
                color: 'blue'
            },
            categoryAxis: {
               color: "blue",
                width: 25,
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false,
                    position: "bottom"
                },

                line: {
                    width: 3,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}"
            }
        });
    }

var series1=[56000, -63000, 74000, 91000, 117000, 158000];


    $(document).ready(function () {
        createChart();

        $("#example").bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);

        var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"),
            firstSeries = chart.options.series;
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [color](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.color) option of the series can be set as a function:

```js
        series: [{
            name: "Total Visits",
            data: series1,
            gap: 1.0,
            spacing: 0,
            color: function(data) {
                if (data.value < 0) {
                    return "green";
                }
            }
        }
```

The Kendo UI version in your jsfiddle however is too old (from 2012) and doesn't support this. You should upgrade to a more recent one.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPUr4/166/

Comment: The JsFiddle link you shared is not the updated one. Can you share it again. And thanks for the reply.\